# Incluing csrf context inside of every render_to_response?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to always include `csrfContext = RequestContext(request)` when I return a `render_to_response` from a view? I notice that many of my views display different content depending if a user is logged in or not. I thought it would be helpful if I included it in every view so I wouldn't have to always add it in. Or, can you give me a reason why this is a bad design choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `context_instance`, this snippet of code is taken from the djandgo documentation.

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                      my_data_dictionary,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Notice the `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`, you need this being returned with your response.

Answer (score 0):

Use [render](http://django.me/render):

```
ctx = {'foo':1}
return render(request,'index.html',ctx)
```

Comment: I need to use render_to_response because I need to pass in a dictionary of values to be displayed on the template.

Comment: Read the documentation please.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use context_processors. You can check [Subclassing Context: RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and [this link](http://blog.madpython.com/2010/04/07/django-context-processors-best-practice/). I hope this will help you.